# AJAX - Pass string empty as NULL value in JSON string to server query

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am using a dropdown list as a filter for an sql query within webmethod that I call through AJAX. The dropdown options are either a number (1,2,3,4...) or "" as the default option if nothing is selected.  Consequently, the query is as follows:

```
SELECT region, customer FROM Tregion  WHERE (@fkidregion is null or fkidregion = @fkidregion)
```

If nothing is selected in the dropdown ("") then a null is passed in the query and if not the option number is used. In the AJAX call, I used the following to pass the dropdown value:

```
 JSON.stringify({ 'fkidregion': $('[id$=ddlRegion]').val() })
```

This works fine if a selection is made, but if the default "" option is selected, the query is not executed properly:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT region, customer FROM Tregion  WHERE (@fkidregion is null or fkidregion = @fkidregion)',N'@fkidregion nvarchar(4000)',@fkidregion=N''
```

But it should be like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT region, customer FROM Tregion  WHERE (@fkidregion is null or fkidregion = @fkidregion)',N'@fkidregion nvarchar(4000)',@fkidregion=NULL
```

So my question is how can I pass a null value within the JSON data or indicate that a null should be used for an empty string.

Here is the code behind if needed:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static BOPData[] PopulateBOPDataFields(string fkidregion)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<BOPData> list = new List<BOPData>();

    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString;
    String strQuery = @"SELECT region, customer FROM Tregion  WHERE (@fkidregion is null or fkidregion = @fkidregion)";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fkidregion", fkidregion);
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
            {
                BOPData data = new BOPData();
                data.region = dtrow["region"].ToString();
                data.customer = dtrow["customer"].ToString();
                list.Add(data);
            }
        }
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}

public class BOPData
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string customer { get; set; }
}
```

And the AJAX function:

```
function PopulateBOPDataFields() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + '/PopulateBOPDataFields',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'fkidregion': $('[id$=ddlRegion]').val() }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $('[id$=gvBOP]').append(
                        "<tr><td>" + data.d[i].region
                        + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].customer
                        + "</td></tr>");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: in this code line `WHERE (@fkidregion is null or fkidregion = @fkidregion)` you could do `WHERE (@fkidregion = '' or fkidregion = @fkidregion)`

Comment: Why not create two queries? One with and one without the `where`. Then your problem is solved.